# How to read the content of file from port

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, listener

I am in needed to use the text data in to a program when someone prints a file.

I have basic ideas about the TCP/IP client and listener programming.
Already I could send and receive txt files between two machines.
But how to receive the file contents if the files were in docx,xlx,pdf or any other format?

My requirement is,

I wanted to use the contents (texts) of a file in to another program when someone prints a file. 
Please suggest me if there is some alternative ways to do it.

Thank in advance.

Comment: The socket who sends should first send the size of the content, after that the socket that receives will know how many bytes to receive for the content. After the content is received you simply save the bytes in whatever fileformat it is. To make it easier the sender could also send the fileformat. If you're asking how to detect which format it is, then you need to do pattern matching on the content to see if it matches a specific file format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted any code I'll write the code part in "my way" but you should have a bit of understanding after reading this.

First on both of the ends ( client and server ) you should apply unified protocol which will describe what data you're sending. Example could be:

***[3Bytes - ASCII extension][4Bytes - lengthOfTheFile][XBytes - fileContents]***

Then in your sender you can receive data according to the protocol which means first your read 3 bytes to decide what format file has, then you read 4 bytes which will basically inform you how large file is incomming. Lastly you have to read the content and write it directly to the file. Example sender could look like this :

```
byte[] extensionBuffer = new byte[3];
if( 3 != networkStream.Read(extensionBuffer, 0, 3))
    return;

string extension = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(extensionBuffer);
byte[] lengthBuffer = new byte[sizeof(int)];
if(sizeof(int) != networkStream.Read(lengthBuffer, 0, 3))
    return;

int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuffer, 0);
int recv = 0;
using (FileStream stream = File.Create(nameOfTheFile + "." + extension))
{
    byte @byte = 0x00;
    while( (@byte = (byte)networkStream.ReadByte() ) != 0x00)
    {
        stream.WriteByte(@byte);
        recv++;
    }
    stream.Flush();
}
```

On the sender part you can read the file extension then open up the file stream get the length of the stream then send the stream length to the client and "redirect" each byte from `FileStream` into a `networkStream`. This can look something like :

```
FileInfo meFile = //.. get the file
byte[] extBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(meFile.Extension);
using(FileStream stream = meFile.OpenRead())
{
    networkStream.Write(extBytes, 0, extBytes.Length);
    networkStream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(stream.BaseStream.Length));
    byte @byte = 0x00;
    while ( stream.Position < stream.BaseStream.Length )
    {
        networkStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());
    }
}
```

This approach is fairly easy to implement and doesn't require big changes if you want to send different file types. It lack some validator but I think you do not require this functionality.

Comment: Another doubt is how to deal if the sender is a printer which prints a file to a IP port, and receiver is my program which catches from that port ?

Comment: @AmjadhNm Then this printer should have some protocol specified in the documentation. Every device that sends something through network have it's own protocol that has to be specified in the documentation.